# Regular Expression to match cross platform newline characters

Tags: python, regex, cross-platform, eol

My program can accept data that has newline characters of \n, \r\n or \r (eg Unix, PC or Mac styles)

What is the best way to construct a regular expression that will match whatever the encoding is?

Alternatively, I could use universal_newline support on input, but now I'm interested to see what the regex would be.

Comment: Just note, `\r` is the _old_ Mac style (and by "old" I mean "OS 9 and before"). Any Mac running OS X (a.k.a. made after 1999) is going to use `\n` like any other Unix.

Comment: When is it useful to match newlines vs. using `'$'` to match the end of the line ?

Comment: @tonfa: When splitting a file into lines via regex.

Comment: @too much php
But wouldn't str.splitlines() works just as well?

Comment: @tonfa: OK so it's not needed often, but it's good to know for other languages that don't have convenient functions like `splitlines()`.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The regex I use when I want to be precise is `"\r\n?|\n"`.

When I'm not concerned about consistency or empty lines, I use `"[\r\n]+"`, I imagine it makes my programs somewhere in the order of 0.2% faster.

Comment: Usually when I'm not concerned about newlines, I'm also not concerned about spaces either.

Comment: What makes your programs faster?

Answer (score 10):

The pattern can be simplified to `\r?\n` for a little performance gain, as you probably don't have to deal with the old Mac style (OS 9 is unsupported since February 2002).