# What is a cross platform regex for removal of line breaks?

Tags: regex, text, parsing, newline

I am sure this has been asked before, but I cannot find it.

Basically, assuming you are parsing a text file of unknown origin and want to replace line breaks with some other delimiter, is this the best regex, or is there another?

`(\r\n)|(\n)|(\r)`

Comment: Do you care about old-Mac-style line breaks (`\r`), or only about Unix and Windows (`\n` and `\r\n`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to match cross platform newline characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331815/regular-expression-to-match-cross-platform-newline-characters)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Fletcher - this did get asked once before.

Here you go: [Regular Expression to match cross platform newline characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331815/regular-expression-to-match-cross-platform-newline-characters)

- Spoiler Alert!

> The regex I use when I want to be
>   precise is "\r\n?|\n".

Answer (score 23):

Do check if your regex engine supports `\R` as a shorthand character class and you will not need to be concerned with the various Unicode newline / linefeed combos. If implemented correctly, you can then match all the various ascii or Unicode line endings transparently using `\R`.

In Unicode you need to detect `NEL` (OS/390 line ending, \x85) `LS` (Line Separator, \x2028) and `PS` (Paragraph Separator, \x2029) if you want to be completely cross platform these days.

It is debatable whether LS, NEL, and PS should be treated as line breaks, line endings, or white space. The XML 1.0 standard, for example, [does not recognize](http://www.w3.org/TR/newline) NEL as a line break character. ECMAScript treats `LS` and `PS` as line breaks but `NEL` as whitespace. [Perl unicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Unicode-Regular-Expression-Support-Level) regexs will treat `VT`, `FF`, `CR`, `CRLF`, `NEL`, `LS` and `PS` as line breaks for the purpose of `^` and `$` regex meta characters.

The [Unicode Implementation Guide](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode4.0.0/ch05.pdf) (section 5.8 and table 5.3) is probably the best bet of what the definitive treatment of what a "newline" is.

If you are only concerned with ascii with the DOS/Windows/Unix/Mac classic variants, the regex equivalent to `\R` is `(?>\r\n|[\r\n])`

In Unicode, the equivalent to `\R` is `(?>\r\n|\n|\x0b|\f|\r|\x85|\x2028|\x2029)` The `\x0b` in there is a vertical tab; once again, this may or may not fit you definition of what a line break is, but that does match the recommendation of the Unicode Implantation. (`FF`, or `\x0C` is not included in the regex since a Form Feed is a new page, not a new line in the definition.)

Comment: "utf8" in your answer should be "Unicode".  UTF-8 is merely one of the Unicode character encodings.

Comment: You are right, but the docs I was referring to (PCRE manual) had the same issue! Edit made...

Comment: In Java, the `\x2028|\x2029` part must be written `\u2028|\u2029`, because `\xhh` is only used for 2-digit hex character values, while `\uhhhh` is used for 4-digit hex character values.

Answer (score 2):

The regex to find any Unicode line terminator should be 
`(?>\x0D\x0A?|[\x0A-\x0C\x85\x{2028}\x{2029}])` rather 
than as drewk wrote it, at least in Perl. Taken directly from the perl
5.10.0 documentation (it was removed in later versions).
Note the braces after `\x`: U+2029 is `\x{2029}`
but `\x2029` is an ASCII whitespace (U+0020) + a digit 2 + a
digit 9. `\n` outside a character class ,is also not guaranteed to match `\x{0a}`.

Answer (score 1):

If your platform does not support the `\R` class as suggested by @dawg above, you may still be able to make a pretty elegant and robust solution if your platform supports negative [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) or character class subtraction (e.g. in Java class subtraction is through the [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) `[x&&[^y]]`).

In most regular expresssion grammars, the dot character is defined to mean "any character except the newline character" (see for example, for JavaScript, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-dot)). If you match something with the following characteristics:

1. not (any character except the newline character) → the newline character; and
2. is whitespace

Since I'm currently working in JavaScript, which AFAIK doesn't have the `\R` shorthand *or* character class subtraction, I can still use negative lookahead to get what I want. The following regular expression matches all newlines:

```
/((?!.)\s)+/g
```

And the following JavaScript code, at least when run in Chrome 42.0.2311.90m on Windows 7, wipes out all the kinds of newlines that JavaScript (i.e. the "ECMAScript" mentioned in @dawg's third paragraph) recognizes:

```js
var input = "hello\r\n\f\v\u2028\u2029 world";
var output = input.replace(/((?!.)\s)+/g, "");
document.write(output); // hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `/[\r\n]+/g` with an empty string `""`.

It'll replace all `\r` and `\n` no matter what order they appear in the string.

Comment: This will replace any number of line breaks with one replacement token.

Comment: @Andreas He wants to remove line breaks.