# regex to select entire paragraph by matching word in first line

Tags: regex

I'm using the following regex to match a paragraph starting with the word "Summary",

```
([^\']*(?=Summary)[^\']*)
```

But its matching all the text: [regex101a](https://regex101.com/r/1cKirB/6)

Also tried

```
(?<=Summary).*?(?=]\.)
```

This does not match anything: [regex101b](https://regex101.com/r/YVhGGe/1)

I believe this has to do with the formatting of the text file.

Here is an example:

```
COMMENT     REVIEWED REFSEQ: This record has been curated by NCBI staff. The
            reference sequence was derived from AC105339.9 and FJ695193.1.
            This sequence is a reference standard in the RefSeqGene project.

        Summary: Adaptor protein complex 3 (AP-3 complex) is a
        heterotrimeric protein complex involved in the formation of
        clathrin-coated synaptic vesicles. The protein encoded by this gene
        represents the beta subunit of the neuron-specific AP-3 complex and
        was first identified as the target antigen in human paraneoplastic
        neurologic disorders. The encoded subunit binds clathrin and is
        phosphorylated by a casein kinase-like protein, which mediates
        synaptic vesicle coat assembly. Defects in this gene are a cause of
        early-onset epileptic encephalopathy. [provided by RefSeq, Feb
        2017].
PRIMARY     REFSEQ_SPAN         PRIMARY_IDENTIFIER PRIMARY_SPAN        COMP
            1-35060             AC105339.9         88079-123138
            35061-35259         FJ695193.1         1-199               c
            35260-57628         AC105339.9         123337-145705
```

And this is what I am aiming to match:

```
    Summary: Adaptor protein complex 3 (AP-3 complex) is a
    heterotrimeric protein complex involved in the formation of
    clathrin-coated synaptic vesicles. The protein encoded by this gene
    represents the beta subunit of the neuron-specific AP-3 complex and
    was first identified as the target antigen in human paraneoplastic
    neurologic disorders. The encoded subunit binds clathrin and is
    phosphorylated by a casein kinase-like protein, which mediates
    synaptic vesicle coat assembly. Defects in this gene are a cause of
    early-onset epileptic encephalopathy. [provided by RefSeq, Feb
    2017].
```

Comment: You second attempt is something like [`Summary.*?\]\.`](https://regex101.com/r/1cKirB/7). That would match from the first word "Summary" (wherever it is) until the next `].`, it can fail on many cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a robust pattern to match your paragraph (using the Multiline flag):

```
^\s+$\n^([ \t]+)Summary.*(?:\n\1[ \t]*\S.*)+
```

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/P6KlBa/2

- "Summary" may appear as the first word in a line. We start by matching an empty line, to make sure "Summary" is at the beginning of a paragraph.
- `([ \t]+)` captures the number of spaces at the beginning of each line. Some flavors have `\h` for [horizontal spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4910093/7586).
- `Summary.*` - The first line start with "Summary".
- `(\n\1([ \t]+)*\S.*)*` - Match more non-empty lines.