# Is there a simple way to search for a sentence in a text that may contain line separators in Java?

Tags: java, string, indexof, multiline, separator

I have this String

```
String text = "Hello world my " + System.lineSeparator() + "name is Bob";
```

I also have this sentence

```
String sentence = "world my name is";
```

I have noticed that you can't find `sentence` in `text` with `indexOf()` because of the line separator. Is there and easy and fast way to still find `sentence` over a multi-line string?

**EDIT:**
I also need to print the string that I found as it was, meaning, If there was a `System.lineSeparator()` in the text where I found `sentence`, I need to print it out with that separator.

Example of i/o:

Input:

```
Hello world my
name is Bob
```

Output:

```
world my
name is
```

Thank you for all the replies!

Comment: `text.replaceAll("\\n", "").indexOf(sentence)` ?

Comment: @alfasin Let's hope OP doesn't use Windows, right? ;P

Comment: @Tom what's windows? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @alfasin

```
text.replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "").indexOf(sentence);
```

Comment: I wold add replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "") also to  sentence.

Comment: Use caution with this - if you use it on a text file that uses `\r\n` (Windows) for new lines but run it on an operating system that uses `\n` (Unix environments) (or the other way around) then it won't work.  See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219014/what-is-a-cross-platform-regex-for-removal-of-line-breaks)