# Ruby regex matching a line in an inputted text file string

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I need to match a line in an inputted text file string and wrap that captured line with a character for example.

For example imagine a text file as such:

```
test
foo
test
bar
```

I would like to use gsub to output:

```
XtestX
XfooX
XtestX
XbarX
```

I'm having trouble matching a line though.  I've tried using regex starting with ^ and ending with $, but it doesn't seem to work?  Any ideas?

I have a text file that has the following in it:

```
test
foo
test
bag
```

The text file is being read in as a command line argument.

So I got (for example just trying to wrap test)

```
string = IO.read(ARGV[0])
string = string.gsub(/^(test)$/,'X\1X')

puts string
```

It outputs the exact same thing that is in the text file.

I've tried

```
string = string.gsub(/^(.*)$/, 'X\1X')
```

This outputs:

```
Xtest
Xfoo
Xtest
Xbar
```

...why?

Okay so I backspaced the last line of the text file and now I am getting this...

```
Xtest
Xfoo
Xbar
XtestX
```

Comment: According to your regex, you're expecting only those lines which starts with test, but your desired output is different!

Comment: @UpasanaShukla what do you mean?  My example code is attempting to wrap test with Xs so my output should include everything the same with XtestX and it doesn't.

Comment: See your desired output, in that replacement is being done in every line whether it starts with test or not. ain't it?

Comment: according to your regex, "foo" shouldn't be replaced with XfooX

Comment: So what.  That doesn't explain why test isn't being wrapped with Xs.

Comment: @Tommy why you stick into `regex`. there are other way to do this.

Comment: @Tommy well, it's working fine on my system, I'm getting the desired output

Comment: What ruby version are you using..?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p194 and that's not stupid!

Comment: are you at ruby1.8.7?

Comment: I'm using the second regex, /^(.*)$/

Comment: I'm using ruby 1.9.3.  And @UpasanaShukla it's stupid because I'm literally copying and pasting exactly what people have been telling me that works and it just doesn't.

Comment: your code also worked fine for me. ruby1.9.3p194

Comment: @Tommy After this line: `string = IO.read(ARGV[0])`, can you put print the string with `p` and give us the output (i.e `p string`)? (I know it should be the same as the file, but i want to make sure)

Comment: Check out my newest update.  It recognized only the last line afted I deleted a blank line at the bottom.

Comment: Does it not recognize returns or something?

Comment: @fmendex 
"test\r\nfoo\r\nbar\r\ntest"
hmm so returns don't count as new lines?

Comment: @Tommy which OS you're using?

Comment: so you're on mac? P.S. stupid mac (:

Comment: it's Windows' line endings!

Comment: Would you know how to fix it Ted?

Comment: probably you should have a look on how regex' `^` and `$` works

Comment: I guess I'm running Mac but am running it through a Windows virtual machine lol so it should be running on Windows.

Comment: the text file which you're using is a windows file?

Comment: Yup the text file is from windows.

Comment: Regular Expression to match cross platform newline characters  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331815/regular-expression-to-match-cross-platform-newline-characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string = "test\r\nfoo\r\ntest\r\nbar"
string = string.gsub(/^test(?=\r?\n)/, 'X\&X').delete(?\r)
puts string
```

Comment: Thanks.  It was definitely a problem with the \r's.  I got rid of them and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me in Ruboto IRB on my phone.  Could you make a self-contained one-line example and post it?  No file IO should be necessary.  What ruby version do you use?

I suspect your program just has a typo.

Comment: My program definitely does not have a typo.  If I print my inputted string I get "test\r\nfoo\r\nbar\r\ntest"  Does it not match the \r's or something?

Comment: puts "test\r\nfoo\r\nbar\r\ntest".gsub(/^(.*)$/, 'X\1X')
that outputs what I've showed with the Xtest
Xfoo
Xbar
XtestX

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because of dos line endings(\r\n), so for getting rid of this, there is a `flip` command (in MAC, if I'm correct) for converting dos line endings to mac line endings(\r). Search for it and convert dos line endings to mac line endings before using that text file.