# How do I remove trailing whitespace using a regular expression?

Tags: regex, whitespace, trailing

I want to remove trailing white spaces and tabs from my code without 
removing empty lines.

I tried:

```
\s+$
```

and:

```
([^\n]*)\s+\r\n
```

But they all removed empty lines too. I guess `\s` matches end-of-line characters too.

---

*UPDATE (2016):*

*Nowadays I automate such code cleaning by using Sublime's [TrailingSpaces](https://github.com/SublimeText/TrailingSpaces) package, with custom/user setting:*

```
"trailing_spaces_trim_on_save": true
```

*It highlights trailing white spaces and automatically trims them on save.*

Comment: Your guess is correct. `\s` matches all kinds of whitespace characters.

Comment: The corresponding *Vi and Vim* question is *[What's the simplest way to strip trailing whitespace from all lines in a file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/454)*

Comment: Here is a [doc entry](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces) on topic.

Comment: @Filipp W: For Vim

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Try just removing trailing spaces and tabs:

```
[ \t]+$
```

Comment: How would I exclude lines which contain only whitespaces, tabs or a mixture of them?

Comment: @DanielF. `([^ \t])[ \t]+$`, but you'd have to replace with `\1` instead of an empty string.

Comment: @Koviko Thanks, but what I meant was that lines which contain only whitespaces or tabs, like indented functions in Python, where indentation is important, should be left as they are. I don't see the suggested regex doing that.

Comment: @DanielF. The regex I posted looks for non-space characters preceding the space characters, and preserves the non-space characters with the `\1` replacement. Lines that consist of only space characters will not match this regex and will be skipped.

Comment: @Koviko This should showcase the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/s7vW5/2/ .The whitespace-only line between foo and bar should contain two spaces. Python's flavor of regex behaves the same.

Comment: @DanielF. In my case, I was using a text editor (Notepad++) that counts each line as a string, not the entire document as a string. As such, newline characters are ignored. To handle the case where newline characters are not ignored, simply add them to the regex: `([^ \t\r\n])[ \t]+$`

Comment: @Koviko: Since your comment is the correct solution to the problem and the answer you've commented on is not, I suggest you post that regex as a separate answer.  Your comment is valuable, but easy to miss.

Comment: For Atom, it's `[ \t]+$`

Answer (score 38):

To remove trailing whitespace while also preserving whitespace-only lines, you want the regex to only remove trailing whitespace *after* non-whitespace characters. So you need to first check for a non-whitespace character. This means that the non-whitespace character will be included in the match, so you need to include it in the replacement.

**Regex:** `([^ \t\r\n])[ \t]+$`

**Replacement:** `\1` or `$1`, depending on the IDE

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you.  Also, the same regex technique modified to use a lookbehind assertion: `(?<![ \t\r\n])[ \t]+$` (replacement pattern should just be blank).

Comment: What  platform uses "\1" as replacement?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Notepad++, for one.

Comment: @PeterMortensen `sed` too.

Comment: This is a built-in function in Notepad++: Menu *Edit* → *Blank Operations* → *Trim Trailing Space*

Comment: @PeterMortensen That will not preserve whitespace-only lines, as in the first line of my answer.

Comment: None of the answers here appear to handle when the text before the trailing spaces contains spaces itself, e.g. "E:\Data\Shared\SCANNED DOCUMENTS      "

Answer (score 19):

The platform is not specified, but in C# ([.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)) it would be:

**Regular expression** (presumes [the multiline option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - the example below uses it):

```
    [ \t]+(\r?$)
```

**Replacement**:

```
    $1
```

---

For an explanation of "\r?$", see *[Regular Expression Options, Multiline Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Multiline)* (MSDN).

#### Code example

This will remove all trailing spaces and all trailing TABs in all lines:

```
string inputText = "     Hello, World!  \r\n" +
                   "  Some other line\r\n" +
                   "     The last line  ";
string cleanedUpText = Regex.Replace(inputText,
                                     @"[ \t]+(\r?$)", @"$1",
                                     RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: The regular expressions in the other two answers do not work in .NET (they don't result in any replacement - the text is left unchanged).

Comment: This also works in Xcode and Swift. Thumbs way up.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Regex to find trailing and leading whitespaces:

```
^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$
```

Comment: Can you provide some context? Where and how did you test it?

Answer (score 3):

If using Visual Studio 2012 and later ([which uses .NET regular expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx)), you can remove trailing whitespace without removing blank lines by using the following regex

Replace `(?([^\r\n])\s)+(\r?\n)`

With `$1`

[image]

---

**Some explanation**

The reason you need the rather complicated expression is that the character class `\s` matches spaces, tabs and newline characters, so `\s+` will match a group of lines containing only whitespace. It doesn't help adding a `$` termination to this regex, because this will still match a group of lines containing only whitespace and newline characters.

You may also want to know (as I did) exactly what the `(?([^\r\n])\s)` expression means. This is an [Alternation Construct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/alternation-constructs-in-regular-expressions), which effectively means match to the whitespace character class if it is not a carriage return or linefeed.

Alternation constructs normally have a true and false part,

`(?( expression ) yes | no )`

but in this case the false part is not specified.

Answer (score 3):

`[ |\t]+$` with an empty replace works.

`\s+($)` with a `$1` replace also works, at least in Visual Studio Code...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove trailing whitespace from lines that have some text, but not just blank lines, here is regex to find: `(\S+)(\s+)$` and replace with `$1`. It finds trailing text as first group, then trailing whitespace just after text as second group. Then replaces both groups by just the first group.

Answer (score 0):

To remove trailing white space while ignoring empty lines I use positive look-behind:

```
(?<=\S)\s+$
```

The look-behind is the way go to exclude the non-whitespace (\S) from the match.

Comment: This matches empty lines.  The match will *start* at the end of a non-empty line, but it will include any empty lines that follow.

Comment: What platform did you use? Perl?

Answer (score 0):

To remove any blank trailing spaces use this:

```
\n|^\s+\n
```

I tested in the [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)) and [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) editors.

Comment: What replacement character did you use? `$1`? Or something else?

Comment: An empty string as the replacement?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, I could not get the `/[\t ]+$/m` to work in PHP.  I tried variants of the other answers here, but still failed.

So, I went with this replacement instead:

```
<?php
$contents = preg_replace('/[\t ]+(\v)/', '$1', $contents);
```

Answer (score -1):

In Java:

```
String str = "    hello world  ";

// prints "hello world" 
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("^(\\s+)|(\\s+)$", ""));
```

Comment: The OP didn't want to remove leading spaces.

Answer (score -4):

You can simply use it like this:

```js
var regex = /( )/g;
```

Sample: [click here](https://regexr.com/4866a)

Comment: Hi @PeterMortensen, it will remove all white spaces

Comment: And what was the question?