# Match a 0-width space in google sheets/datastudio?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, looker-studio

I'm trying to build a regular expression that can work on Google Sheets and DataStudio. The regex must check that a URL is correctly built from start to end, with no trailing characters except whitespace.

Below a test version that works for my case ([here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q-YpBnrbJXRq0J83GEl-Du-iRfERUjF7GYDUMHcg4qw/edit?usp=sharing) it's application)

```
^(http[s]?:\/\/)([^:\/\s]+)(\/\?)((?:(?:\w+=\w+)&?)+)$
```

Problem is that some urls in my database contain a leading or trailing zero-width space (200B  code). This invalidates the query at times it shouldn't.
I don't have a way to clean the data before I read it, and I can't find a valid code within this regex dialect to include it in the match.

Is there a possible workaround to this?

Comment: you want to validate or extract?

Comment: I probably won't need extracting, it's only present in the sheet to test some pieces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove trailing whitespace using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532340/how-do-i-remove-trailing-whitespace-using-a-regular-expression) Modify the last section `$` with `[ \t]+$`

Answer (score 1):

You can always just remove it before the REGEXMATCH is applied, e.g.:

`=REGEXMATCH(SUBSTITUTE(E7;CHAR(8203);"");$D$2)`

or

`=REGEXMATCH(REGEXREPLACE(E7;CHAR(8203);"");$D$2)`

You could also "sandwich" the REGEX expression you have between instances of `[^!-~]*` (which would essentially allow anything outside of the printable range of English characters):

`^[^!-~]*(http[s]?:\/\/)([^:\/\s]+)(\/\?)((?:(?:\w+=\w+)&?)+)[^!-~]*$`