# RegExp exclusion, looking for a word not followed by another

Tags: regex

I am trying to search for all occurrences of "Tom" which are not followed by "Thumb".

I have tried to look for

```
Tom ^((?!Thumb).)*$
```

but I still get the lines that match to Tom Thumb.

Comment: Even in a simple case like this, it is always helpful to have some sample input and expected output. e.g., do you want to match just 'Tom' or 'Tom + everything to the end of the line'?

Comment: I will try to be more explicit.  I want to find any occurrence of "Tom" anywhere in a line, but I do not want to see any line that contains "Tom Thumb"

Answer (score 52):

You don't say what flavor of regex you're using, but this should work in general:

```
 Tom(?!\s+Thumb)
```

Comment: You may thing that it will work for ocurrences such as "TomThumb" (without spaces between them). For it to work, you will need to remove "\s+" from your regex. Example: Tom(?!Thumb)

Answer (score 35):

In case you are not looking for whole words, you can use the following regex:

```
Tom(?!.*Thumb)
```

If there are more words to check after a wanted match, you may use

```
Tom(?!.*(?:Thumb|Finger|more words here))
Tom(?!.*Thumb)(?!.*Finger)(?!.*more words here)
```

To make `.` match line breaks please refer to [How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118)

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vB4hJ1/1)

If you are looking for whole words (i.e. a whole word `Tom` should only be matched if there is no whole word `Thumb` further to the right of it), use

```
\bTom\b(?!.*\bThumb\b)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vB4hJ1/2)

Note that:

- `\b` - matches a leading/trailing word boundary
- `(?!.*Thumb)` -  is a *negative lookahead* that fails the match if there are any 0+ characters (depending on the engine including/excluding linebreak symbols) followed with `Thumb`.

Comment: I will never master regex :S

Answer (score 1):

`Tom(?!\s+Thumb)` is what you search for.