# Regex to match parts of line and negative-lookup the rest of the line (not match a word)

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Is there a regex, that matches
*haha***foo***bla***ba***bla*
and does not match
*haha***foo***bla***bar***bla*

Because I am looking for ...foo... and don't want to have ...bar... anywhere after the ...foo...

*haha* and *bla* symbolize junk/noise.

UPDATE:
At first I tried with

```
foo.*(?!bar)
```

--> was not successful

Comment: Certainly, you can use a negative lookahead. What is your regex flavor?

Comment: I ask what the flavor is because it happens people are tagging their questions with regex-negation and regex-lookarounds tags looking for a RE2 (Google Analytics, eg.) compatible regexps where one cannot use lookarounds.

Comment: I would say, that "normal" regex-es - meaning lookarounds are available - are the default in questions. If someone needs a RE2 solution, (s)he should give a hint that this is a special case.

Comment: BTW I don't get the -1 on my post ... not that I care so much, but was just wondering why :)

Comment: It is a duplicate of [RegExp exclusion, looking for a word not followed by another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375045/regexp-exclusion-looking-for-a-word-not-followed-by-another). Also, you need to always include what you have tried to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foo(?!.*bar)
```

- `foo` - match *foo*
- `(?!)` - that isn't followed by
- `bar` - *bar*
- `.*` - with any amount of characters in between

Comment: So, what if the engine is RE2?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, according to OP's reaction - it's not. 

Comment: It's not RE2, I am able to do lookarrounds. Thanks, I was wondering where to put the `.*` part. I tried `foo.*(?!bar)` which didn't work. I didn't realize, that I can use `.*` inside the negative lookahead.

Comment: @user1414745: Update the question with what you tried.