# Regex - match some words, ignore other words on the same line

Tags: regex

I have found countless 'match anything except for' examples, but not any for what I want.
I do **not** want to match **"anything"** [except for x]!

I want to match "This is a line"  but not if the string 'do not' is present.  therefore, **only line B** should contain a match

`(A) This is nonsense and none of this should match
(B) This is a line and we want part of it to be matched
(C) This is a line and we do not want anything to be matched
(D) This is nonsense and none of this should match`

Can someone please explain how to do this?  Are capture groups absolutely necessary?  I'm not trying to capture anything but I'll definitely use it if I have to.

I've played around on https://regex101.com/ but I am not getting anywhere.  The assistance of regex veterans is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `\bThis is a line\b(?!.*\bdo not\b)` or `^(?!.*\bdo not\b).*\bThis is a line\b` if `do not` can appear before the `This is a line`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39719452/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

Use negative look ahead:

a(?!b)

This would match "ax" or "a" but not "ab"

Negative lookahead makes the substring not match if b (example above) is after a (example above)