# Removing a substring between two characters (java)

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I have a java string such as this:

```
String string = "I <strong>really</strong> want to get rid of the strong-tags!";
```

And I want to remove the  tags. I have some other strings where the tags are way longer, so I'd like to find a way to remove everything between "<>" characters, including those characters.

One way would be to use the built-in string method that compares the string to a regEx, but I have no idea how to write those.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Caution is advised when using regex to parse HTML (due its allowable complexity), however for "simple" HTML, and simple text (text without literal `<` or `>` in it) this will work:

```
String stripped = html.replaceAll("<.*?>", "");
```

Answer (score 4):

To avoid Regex:

```
String toRemove = StringUtils.substringBetween(string, "<", ">");
String result = StringUtils.remove(string, "<" + toRemove + ">");
```

For multiple instances:

```
String[] allToRemove = StringUtils.substringsBetween(string, "<", ">");
String result = string;
for (String toRemove : allToRemove) {
  result = StringUtils.remove(result, "<" + toRemove + ">"); 
}
```

> [Apache StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) functions are null-, empty-, and no match- safe

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```java
String stripped = html.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
String stripped = html.replaceAll("<[^<>]*>", "");
```

where `<[^>]*>` matches substrings starting with `<`, then zero or more chars other than `>` (or the chars other than `<` and `>` if you choose the second version) and then a `>` char.

Note that `<.*?>`

- is less efficient than a negated character class (see [Which would be better non-greedy regex or negated character class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41269297/3832970))
- does not find substrings spanning across multiple lines (see [How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981809/3832970)), but it can be solved with `(?s)<.*?>`, `<(?s:.)*?>`, `<[\w\W]*?>`, and many other not-so-efficient variations.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/HAPzJP/1).