# Java regular expression : how to get rid of text inside ()?

Tags: java, regex

I have some text like this : `Javascript (12+ years), Java (10 years)`
How to use regular expression to extract the following text : `Javascript, Java`

I've seen that link, have you tried it ? It doesn't work in my case !
The answer below works : `replaceAll("\\((.+)\\)","")`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462209/removing-a-substring-between-two-characters-java

Comment: @MC10 Thanks for the link, voted to close as dupe.

Comment: So, you have 10 years of java experience, but can't figure this out?

Comment: Frank, I must say I'm somewhat disappointed. With that much rep, you should know to search before asking on SO.

Comment: This is trivial. What's not trivial is to define what `text inside ()` means.

Comment: @DanGetz Yeah, I retract my statement. You and sln are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex

```
 str= str.replaceAll("\((.+)\)", "");
```

Comment: You probably meant to use `replaceAll` which uses a regex pattern.

Comment: @Bubeltan yes well pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(.*?)(\s*\(.*?\))
```

With substitution `$1`

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/pD8oK9/1)