# preg_match returns empty array

Tags: php

I always use `preg_match` and it always works fine,
but today I was trying to get a content between two html tags `<code: 1>DATA</code>`

And I have a problem, which my code explains:

```
function findThis($data){
    preg_match_all("/\<code: (.*?)\>(.*?)\<\/code\>/i",$data,$conditions);
    return $conditions;
}

    // plain text
    // working fine

    $data1='Some text...Some.. Te<code: 1>This is a php code</code>';

    //A text with a new lines
    // Not working..

    $data2='some text..
    some.. te
    <code: 1>
    This is a php code
    ..
    </code>
    ';

    print_r(findThis($data1));

    // OUTPUT
    // [0][0] => <code: 1>This is a php code</code>
    // [1][0] => 1
    // [2][0] => This is a php code

    print_r(findThis($data2));

    //Outputs nothing!
```

Comment: The `.*` placeholder will not match newlines, unless you specify the 'dotall' modifier `/s`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the . character in PHP is a wildcard for **anything but newline**. Examples including newlines would break. What you want to do is add the "s" flag to the end of your pattern, which modifies the . to match absolutely everything (including newlines).

```
/\<code: (.*?)\>(.*?)\<\/code\>/is
```

See here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.internal-options.php

Comment: Thank you very much Sean Johnson, it's now working fine.. but another question, if i used this function with a very long text, i will get error? is there a limit? if so, How can i increase the limit size?

Comment: The limit is however much memory you allocate to PHP. You'll have to be dealing with some really large data to run into that limit.

Comment: Thanks Sean, finally the ten minutes is end, and i am able to accept your answer..

Comment: Why i use ( /i ) ? i use it but i don't now the reason, i am beginner in regexp

Comment: Please see the link I posted for an explanation on regexp flags.