# Regex match all

Tags: .net, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression)

I am currently making a software, working like Notepad++

I am using regex to find the words, and give them a color. However; I got stuck on coloring the multiple line comments.

Sample: `/* This is a multiline comment */`

Using my currently regex: `/\*.*?\*/` - It is working properly until a newline is being placed.

So it matches: `/*This, for instance!*/`
But does not match:

```
/* This kind of comments
 - Where multiple lines is placed...
*/
```

So I was wondering, instead of using the [dot] for finding the words inside the comment, can I then use some other, **match all** operator?

- I am using C#s class '**Regex**'

Comment: specifically [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2626317/1633117)

Comment: A side note: you won't get far with regular expressions. You need a context-free grammar. For example what happens if `*/` is inside a string (assuming you create syntax highlighting for a programming language).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one might work for you.

```
/\**.*?\*/
```

**[RegexOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx)** must be set to `MultiLine`

Screenshot from RegexBuddy,

[image]

Comment: any comments for downvote please? :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but isn't it exactly the other way round? Don't you need to set RegexOptions.Singleline?

Comment: @m.buettner but the user want to be `multiline` write?

Comment: Quoting from the page you linked yourself: "Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except \n)." ... so I guess this means, "Singleline" means "treat everything in the string as if it was in one line"