# regular expression to match pipe separated strings with pipe escaping

Tags: regex, split

I'd like to get the single strings of a pipe-separated string, with "pipe escaping" support, e.g.:

```
fielda|field b |field\|with\|pipe\|inside
```

would get me:

```
array("fielda", "field b ", "field|with|pipe|inside")
```

How would I reach that goal with a regular expression?

Comment: What language are you using?  Chances are that the language already supports something like this for you with a CSV parsing function or module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Split  by this (?<!\\)\|
```

See demo.The lookbehind makes sure `|` is not after `\`.

https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/15

Answer (score 1):

This should work too:

```
((?:[^\\|]+|\\\|?)+)
```

The regex will capture everything up to a single `|` (including `\|`)

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/zM7yV5/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

An other way with php, using `strtr` that replace `\|` with a placeholder:

```
$str = 'field a|field b|field\|with\|pipe\|inside';
$str = strtr($str, array('\|' => '#'));
$result = array_map(function ($i) {
    return strtr($i, '#', '|');
}, explode('|', $str));
```

Comment: I don't see any specific language indicated by the asker.

Answer (score 0):

You may **match** these items with

```
(?:[^\\|]|\\[\s\S])+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qQfqdt/1).

**NOTE**: If you need to split on a *character other than `|`* just replace it within the first [*negated character class*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), `[^\\|]`. Just note that you will have to escape `]` (unless it is placed right after `[^`) and `-` (if not at the start/end of the class).

The `[\s\S]` can be replaced with a `.` in many engines and pass the appropriate option [to make it match across line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981809/3832970).

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3A%5B%5E%5C%5C%7C%5D%7C%5C%5C%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D)%2B):

[image]

JS demo:

```js
console.log(
   "fielda|field b |field\\|with\\|pipe\\|inside".match(/(?:[^\\|]|\\[\s\S])+/g)
)
// =>  ["fielda", "field b ", "field\|with\|pipe\|inside"]
```