# PHP's preg_match_all: regex to get pipe-separeted fields with escaping

Tags: php, regex

I already asked the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200875/regular-expression-to-match-pipe-separated-strings-with-pipe-escaping) how to get the string fields from a pipe-separated string with pipe-escaping, and got an answer that worked well on http://www.regex101.com: a regex to get the single words of a pipe-separated string, supporting pipe-escaping.

Unfortunately this does not seem to work in PHP's preg_match_all() function:

```
$input   = 'word1| word 2 |word\|3';
$pattern = '/(?P<w>(?:[^\\|]+|\\\|?)+)/';
$matches = array();

preg_match_all($pattern,$input,$matches);

// Expected $matches: $matches['w'] => array('word1', ' word 2 ', 'word\|3')
```

What am I missing? The example is working fine here:

https://regex101.com/r/zM7yV5/4

Comment: it's because of the forward slash as delimiter. Just use a different php delimiter with the same regex. That is, `$pattern = '~(?P<w>(?:[^\\|]+|\\\|?)+)~';`

Comment: No, it's not: 1) I'm not matching against a '/' character, and 2) using another delimiter does not work, either. See vks' answer below, which is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$re = "/(?P<w>(?:[^\\\\|]+|\\\\\\|?)+)/";
$str = "word1| word 2 |word\|3";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. So many backslashes :-( Why do I have to escape the backslash here, but not e.g. in something like <code>/\d+/</code>? I think I don't need to escape the backslash itself for the PHP string, as I am using single quotes...?

Comment: No, here the delimiter was not the problem, as I dont want to match '/' itself. Even with another delimiter I need that amount of backslashes.

Comment: @AlexSchenkel try with `~`.You might not need these many `\\`.