# How to extract FirstName and LastName from html tags with regex?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have response body which contains

```
"<h3 class="panel-title">Welcome 
                                First Last </h3>"
```

I want to fetch 'First Last' as a output

The regular expression I have tried are

```
"Welcome(\s*([A-Za-z]+))(\s*([A-Za-z]+))" 
"Welcome \s*([A-Za-z]+)\s*([A-Za-z]+)"
```

But not able to get the result. If I remove the newline and take it as 
`"<h3 class="panel-title">Welcome First Last </h3>"` it is detecting in online regex maker.

Comment: Regex and HTML are not good friends.

Comment: You regex works: [Group 2 and 4 contain your data](https://regex101.com/r/dK9sE0/1).

Comment: Check out this SO question and answer about matching across multiple lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression

Comment: where do you write that: javascript or php ?

Comment: I want to fetch it in jmeter Regex Extractor

Comment: In Jmeter, the texts are in `$2$` and `$4$` variables. Try using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is the carriage return between "Welcome" and the user name.  If you use the "single-line mode" flag (?s) in your regex, it will ignore newlines.  Try these:

```
(?s)Welcome(\s*([A-Za-z]+))(\s*([A-Za-z]+)) 

(?s)Welcome \s*([A-Za-z]+)\s*([A-Za-z]+)
```

(this works in jMeter and any other java or php based regex, but not in javascript.  In the comments on the question you say you're using javascript and also jMeter - if it is a jMeter question, then this will help.  if javaScript, try one of the other answers)

Comment: Hey ... thanks ! Worked for me ... Your guess was right. I was struggling with the newline .

Comment: Thanks Shivalika.  It would be great if you marked my answer as "correct"

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually I don't recommend regex for this kind of work. DOM manipulation plays at its best.

but you can use following regex to yank text:

```
/(?:<h3.*?>)([^<]+)(?:<\/h3>)/i
```

See demo at https://regex101.com/r/wA2sZ9/1

This will extract First and Last names including extra spacing. I'm sure you can easily deal with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

In jmeter reg exp extractor you can use:

```
<h3 class="panel-title">Welcome(.*?)</h3>
```

Then take value using $1$.

In the data you shown welcome is followed by enter.If actually its part of response then you have to use \n.

```
  <h3 class="panel-title">Welcome\n(.*?)</h3>
```

Otherwise above one is enough.

First verify this in jmeter using regular expression tester of response body.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome([\s\S]+?)<

Try this, it will definitely work.

Answer (score -1):

Regular expressions are greedy by default, try this

```
Welcome\s*([A-Za-z]+)\s*([A-Za-z]+)
```

Groups 1 and 2 contain your data

Check it [here](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=94272)

Comment: *Regular expressions are greedy by default* is totally incorrect. Also, OP regex works. There is no need re-writing the regex for OP. OP needs to know HOW to use that regex in jmeter.

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by OP?

Comment: OP = "original poster". The gender neutral version of the person who asked the question