# regex : how to match word ending with parentheses ")"

Tags: regex, match, parentheses

I want to match string ending with ')' .
I use pattern :

```
 "[)]\b" or ".*[)]\b"
```

It should match the string :

```
x=main2.addMenu('Edit')
```

But it doesn't work. What is wrong ?

Comment: What language are you using?  Why not just use `\)\b` ?

Comment: In JS, maybe this: `(.*?\)$)` - capture everything up to an escaped ')' at the end of the string.

Comment: `^.*?\)$` is what you want I guess

Comment: Thanks for the reply , the "\)" doesn't work. I tried it here : https://regex101.com

Answer (score 3):

The \b only matches a position at a word boundary. Think of it as a `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)` where \w is any alphanumeric character and \W is any non-alphanumeric character. The parenthesis is non-alphanumeric so won't be matched by \b.

Just match a parethesis, followed by the end of the string by using `\)$`

Comment: Thanks , it's good explaination . I use this website : https://regex101.com . I tried that '$' and it works. But if i have multiline strings then i will match the last line. So maybe i have to break down that multiline first into separate lines. Or any other solution ?

Comment: If you want to write a regex that matches multiple lines then you will need to add a modifier which depends on which language you're using. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/159118/2516183) question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to capture a string ending in `)` (and not just find a trailing `)`), then you can use this in JS:

```
(.*?\)$)
```

`(....)` - captures the defined content;

`.*?` - matches anything up to the next element;

`\)$` - a `)` at the end of the string (needs to be escaped);

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yH6mR0/1)

Answer (score 2):

The `\b` word boundary is ambiguous: after a word character, it requires that the next character must a non-word one or the end of string. When it stands after a non-word char (like `)`) it requires a word character (letter/digit/underscore) to appear right after it (not the end of the string here!).

So, there are three solutions:

- Use `\B` (a non-word boundary): `.*[)]\B` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS2pH9/1)) that will  not allow matching if the `)` is followed with a word character
- Use `.*[)]$` with `MULTILINE` mode (add `(?m)` at the start of the pattern or add the `/m` modifier, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS2pH9/2))
- Emulate the multiline mode with an alternation group: `.*[)](\r?\n|$)` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS2pH9/3))