# Regex Escape word in pattern

Tags: php, regex, escaping

I would like to match the word `mat($MPC)` in my regex, but because of the parentheses it does'nt work.

Is there a way that I can classify the word as text and not as a regex expression.

```
$text = "1.5*mat($MPC)*AMOUV+NBSC";
$word = "mat($MPC)";
preg_replace('/\b'.$word.'\b/u','50',$text);
```

I'm not using str_replace because sometime I need to replace NBS or NBSC. So when I'm replacing it need to be a whole word.

Thank

Comment: `preg_replace('/\b'.preg_quote($word, '/').'\b/u','50',$text);`

Comment: might be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858628/regex-how-to-match-word-ending-with-parentheses) can help you.