# unique check using regex for string separated by comma

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

so i am trying to come up with a perfect regex for checking a set of predefined string separated by commas without any repeat. Currently i've been able to achive this

```
^((IN|THE|BUSH|COM|NET|ALL)\s*[,]{0,1}\s*)+$
```

its works fine for its purpose apart from the fact that its doesn't check for unique values

example is "IN, THE, COM" without quotes 
this is a correct format

but having this is incorrect

"IN, COM, THE, COM"

i need a regex that works with java for this same task

Comment: Please, post the code lines where you do this.

Comment: You're trying to run two *different* validations with a single regex. Don't do it: even if it's possible it's difficult to read & maintain.

Comment: right now i don't code that does that in java, am checking with online regex validator, and onces it works i intend to integrate it to my code. Thanks

Comment: thanks for your advice @alfasin i will keep that in mind

Comment: Once your regex is validated, run another regex check for unique values. You can achieve this with a negative lookahead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469320/regex-only-match-unique-string-occurrences

Comment: `[,]{0,1}` is identical to `,?` btw

Comment: That's right @ctwheels

Comment: I think you're looking for `^(IN|THE|BUSH|COM|NET|ALL)(?!.*\b\1\b)(?:\h*,\h*(IN|THE|BUSH|COM|NET|ALL)(?!.*\b\2\b))*$`

Comment: Thanks for you advice @PierreFrançois, my framework will only accept one regex for one field, i cannot custom that

Comment: Thans @ctwheels, it works for some inputs only like "THE,IN,COM,NET,THE" but for somethings like this, it doesn't work "THE,IN,COM,NET,NET" so it check for repeatation on the first occurrence only

Comment: @StarBlazh it works for that too.

Comment: Sorry, change `\h*` to `\s*` (I needed `\h*` for multiline online)

Comment: Thanks @ctwheels u'm it doesn't work for my case, it only check for repeatation on the first occurrence only e.g IN, THE  it check for multiple occurrence of IN and not for THE or other sets

Comment: @StarBlazh it checks for multiple occurrences regardless of location.

Comment: lemme confirm that again, Thanks for the head up

Comment: Why not split on comma and check multiple array element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use this regex which uses a negative lookahead `(?!.*\1)` the check if what is following is not what is captured in the first group `\1`

[`^(?:(IN|THE|BUSH|COM|NET|ALL)\h*,?\h*(?!.*\1))+$`](https://regex101.com/r/Arugmz/2)

Comment: Great, works like charm, i wasn't thinking to that direction. Thanks

Comment: "checking a set of predefined string separated by commas without any repeat."