# Regex to search for unique last names in XML

Tags: regex

I have last names in an XML file that I would like to capture, which are unique. I am going off this other StackOverflow answer to start: [Only match unique string occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469320/only-match-unique-string-occurrences) I am not able to match the strings that I have with this to return one Adams and one Yellow.

```
\b(.*<LastName>(.*)<\/LastName>)\b(?![\s\S]*\b\1\b)

              <LastName>Adams</LastName>
              <LastName>Adams</LastName>
              <LastName>Yellow</LastName>
```

https://regex101.com/r/2wLsm5/1

Comment: What tool are you using, and why are you not using an XML parser? Or even just pipe it to `sort -u`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

`/<LastName>(\w+)<\/LastName>(?!.*<LastName>\1<\/LastName>)/gsm` (note the flags, they're important)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O1RocE/3)

The issue was that your `(.*)` to match the name allowed it to match across multiple lines. I replaced it with `\w+` so it only matches word characters (depending on your needs something a little more international might be needed, though).

Comment: Also of note: The name will be in capture group 1. The whole match will include the tags. This could be changed with look-arounds.

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't know that was searching multiple lines. Thank you very much for explaining that!

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the name of the tag and it's content.
Then use the backreferences in the negative lookahead.

A lazy search `.*?` for the tag's content helps here.

```
<(LastName)>(.*?)<\/\1>(?![\s\S]*?<\1>\2<\/\1>)
```

Test on regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/2wLsm5/3)