# Regex for not-empty-string but allowing linebreaks

Tags: java, regex, string, validation, textarea

I'm using a regex in my validation to determine whether an input on a field is empty.

The regex is as follows: ^(?=\s*\S).*$

However, if the user presses enter, thereby creating a linebreak, on that textarea and writes something after it, the validation fails.

What should I add to that regex so, that it allows linebreaks?

Comment: `.` can be replaced with `[\s\S]`. Or in this case - `^\s*\S[\s\S]*$`

Comment: I also added [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression) to close reasons as it is generic for all regex flavors.

Comment: That works. Thank you