# Regexp for spam filter

Tags: regex, email, outlook, smtp

I've trying to set up some filters from spam mail on our Microsoft Exchange server.

I need to check the letter ad spam if there is in header "Recieved" more then 3 dots and it doesn't containt word "outlook"

Checking dots can be done by regex `.*\..*\..*\..*`

Checking if string doesn't contain word "outlook" can be done by regex `((?!outlook).)*$`

I try to unite then in one expression `^(?=.*\..*\..*\..*)(?=((?!outlook).)*$)` but doesn't work:(

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(?!.*outlook)[^.]*(?:\.[^.]*){0,2}$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HJ7lXv/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*outlook)` - no `outlook` substring allowed anywhere on the line
- `[^.]*` - any 0+ chars other than a `.`
- `(?:\.[^.]*){0,2}` - 0, 1 or 2 occurrences of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[^.]*` -  any 0+ chars other than a `.`
- `$` -  end of string.

So, any string will be matched that has no `outlook` and that has 0, 1 or 2 dots only.

Note that in case you have multiple lines there, you will have to [make `.` match multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981809/3832970).