# PySpark 2 - Regex replace everything before <BR>

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

I have a record which is like

```
"_row"\n"<BR>Datetime:2018.06.30^
Name:ABC^
Se:4^
Machine:XXXXXXX^
InnerTrace:^
AdditionalInfo:^
<ER>
```

I would want to remove everything before 
 in each record. Is there an easy way to do this with spark dataframe

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

data.select(f.regexp_replace(pattern='\n<BR>',replacement="<BR>",str="row")
```

something like this? What should the pattern be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match all characters until the beginning of the string, you could use `.*<BR>`. However, this does not match line breaks (`\n`). I found a solution for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression), so our pattern could be `(?s).*<BR>`. A working example is given below, hope this helps!

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([('''"_row"\n"<BR>Datetime:2018.06.30^
Name:ABC^
Se:4^
Machine:XXXXXXX^
InnerTrace:^
AdditionalInfo:^
<ER>''',), ],schema=['text'])

df = df.withColumn('text_cleaned',
               F.regexp_replace(F.col('text'),pattern='(?s).*<BR>',replacement="<BR>"))
```

Let's verify that that worked;

```
print(df.select('text').collect()[0][0])
```

outputs

```
"_row"
"<BR>Datetime:2018.06.30^
Name:ABC^
Se:4^
Machine:XXXXXXX^
InnerTrace:^
AdditionalInfo:^
<ER>
```

and

```
print(df.select('text_cleaned').collect()[0][0])
```

outputs:

```
<BR>Datetime:2018.06.30^
Name:ABC^
Se:4^
Machine:XXXXXXX^
InnerTrace:^
AdditionalInfo:^
<ER>
```