# Using Regex to find text within block

Tags: c#, regex

So I have a text block something like below,

```
#start
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
#end

*--Similar blocks-*
```

I used this

```
Regex.Matches(text,@"#start(.*?)#end",RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

regex for this above block.

The thing is when I try matching this Regex through Notepad++ find options it works, but through C# Regex.Matches function it fails.

I don't know what exactly is the problem. But hope you people can help me ! :)

Comment: Welcome new user!  this may help also https://stackoverflow.com/a/159139/294884

Comment: You should use `RegexOptions.Singleline` too.

Comment: 'MultiLine' option is not neseccary, but 'SingleLine' is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `Singleline` regex mode. Try this code, it will print text between `#start` and `#end`

```
var input = @"#start
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
#end

#start
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
#end";

var reges = new Regex("#start(.*?)#end", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var blocks = reges.Matches(input).Cast<Match>();
foreach (var block in blocks)
    Console.WriteLine(block.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: I will try this code tomorrow and will let you know :)

Answer (score 2):

The dot character matches any character **except newlines**. Thus it will not match anything after the `#start` initial string. Try the following regex: `#start(.|\s)+?#end` (tested [here](http://regexr.com/418ve)).

As pointed out by other user's comments/answers, another simpler solution would be activating the "single line" regex option, which forces the regex matchers to consider the dot character as **any character, including newlinew characters**. This would allow OP's original regex to be used without modifications. Single line regex mode could be activated by passing the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option while matching the regex, as follows:

`Regex.Matches(text, @"#start(.*?)#end", RegexOptions.Singleline);`

Comment: another way to do it - just add a /s modifier at the end

Comment: Thanks this works like a charm :)

Comment: This is a very inefficient solution. Never use `(.|\s)+?`, it will make every regex slow and will decrease the code performance. Use `RegexOptions.Singleline` with a mere `.`. So, you may use `@"(?s)#start(.*?)#end"`, `@"#start(?s:.*?)#end"`, or `new Regex("#start(.*?)#end", RegexOptions.Singleline)`

Comment: I focused on explaining the reason why OP's original solution didn't work, not the performance side. I'm updating the answer to include these observations.