# Extract phone number from text in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract phone number from text. I able to extract phone number from text when all digits are presents on single line. But When some digits are present in next line then regex is not working.

Here is my text:

```
I will be out of the office. Please send me an email and text my mobile +45
20 32 40 08 if any urgency.
```

In above text **+45** is on first line and **20 32 40 08** presents on second line. I unable to extract phone numbers from text when text like above text. When digits are present on same single line then it's working fine.

Here is my regex:

```
reg_phonestyle = re.compile(r'(\d{2}[-\/\.\ \s]??\d{2}[-\/\.\ \s]??\d{2}[-\/\.\ \s]??\d{2}[-\/\.\ \s]??\d{2}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\/\.\ \s]??\d{4}|\d{3}[-\/\.\ \s]??\d{4})')
```

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression

Comment: Try matching any number of whitespaces, `.`, `-` chars between digits and remove whitespace from the match afterwards. Try https://ideone.com/vTbqGp, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZQjRH2/1). Also, if that is not yielding the results you want, try replacing `[-\/\.\ \s]??`s with `(?:\s*|[-/.]`s (see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZQjRH2/2)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, It's not working

Comment: It is working and you can see it in my numerous demos.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, It's adding '\n' into phone numbers

Comment: ...and `re.sub(r'\s+', '', m.group())` removes it.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an additional flag to perform a MULTILINE search.
Given your example I propose the following solution:

```
import re

input_str = '''                                                                 

I will be out of the office. Please send me an email and text my mobile +45     
20 32 40 08 if any urgency.                                                     

'''
phone_reg = re.compile("([0-9]{2,4}[-.\s]{,1}){5}", re.MULTILINE)

print(phone_reg.search(input_str).group(0))
```

Where this regexp find 5 groups of: 2 to 4 digits followed by 0 or 1 spacing character

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This is my way to get phone number. actually i want more examples to verify my regex.

```
import re
strs = '''                                                                 
I will be out of the office. Please send me an email and text my mobile +45     
20 32 40 08 if any urgency.                                                     
'''
phone = re.compile("(?<=mobile\s)(.?[0-9]|\s)+", re.S)

print( " ".join(phone.search(strs).group(0).split()) ) # remove \n and space and etc.
```