# Postgresql how match content like "[\s\S]*?" in regex

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to replace content of long Strings in postgres column.

The match pattern is `"{Begin}{anything}{mid}{anything}{end}"`, and the match is non-greedy version.

Begin, mid, end is fixed content while anything can include character, number, space, newline etc.

With common regex we can use `([\s\S]*?)` but it doesn't work well in Postgres.
How can I do with this.

Example:
I have a DB column name "descriptor", I want to match content

```
 "<function type="class"> {anything} <arg name="class.name">com.ehi.jira.plugin.workflow {anything} </function>",
```

and it should match the shortest content.With common regex I will use

```
"<function type="class">([\s\S]*?)<arg name="class.name">com.ehi.jira.plugin.workflow([\s\S]*?)</function>".
```

But it doesn't work in postgresql.

Comment: You need to use `.` instead of `[\s\S]`, it is all discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981809/3832970)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `%` operator to match any number of characters:

```
select * from table where col like '<function type="class">%<arg name="class.name">com.ehi.jira.plugin.workflow%</function>'
```

A sample query to test this :

```
postgres=# select * from (select '<function type="class"> {anything} <arg name="class.name">com.ehi.jira.plugin.workflow {anything} </function>' as col) as t  where col like '<function type="class">%<arg name="class.name">com.ehi.jira.plugin.workflow%</function>' ;

                                                      col
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 <function type="class"> {anything} <arg name="class.name">com.ehi.jira.plugin.workflow {anything} </function>
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I find my question is wrong.
I want it contain "<function" and "</function>" only once.
But it seems regex can't do it.
In detail, the matched content should be "<function type="class">chars numbers newlines spaces etc<arg name="class.name">com.ehi.jira.plugin.workflow chars numbers newlines spaces etc</function>", and it contains "<function type="class">" and </function> only once.
Can regex do that?

Comment: You can force <function> to be the beginning and end with `^` and `$` characters

Comment: The content is generated by other application, I can't set the rule.
I realize it's a strange requirement. I think it can't be done. Thanks for your kindly answer.