# Find DATE match starting from end of string

Tags: regex

I have the following RegEx syntax that will match the first date found.

```
([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)
```

However, I would like to start from the end of the content and search backwards. In other words, in the below example, my syntax will always match the first date, but I want it to match the last instead.

```
Some Text here
01/02/15
Some additional
text here.
10/04/14
Ending text
here
```

I believe this is possible by using a negative lookahead, but all my attempts failed at this because I don't understand RegEx enough. Help would be appreciated.

Note: my application uses RegEx PCRP.

Comment: The rule is  like this: `pattern(?!.*pattern)`. If `.` does not match line break chars, [make it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the dot match a newline using for example an inline modifier `(?s)` and match until the end of the string.

Then make use of backtracking until the last occurrence of the date like pattern and precede the first digit with a word boundary.

Use `\K` to forget what was matched and match the date like pattern.

```
^(?s).*\b\K[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wPTWqU/1)

Note that the pattern is a very broad match and does not validate a date itself.

Comment: For some reason, both of those match everything up to the last date. I only want it to match on the last date. If you look here at my original regex, it only matches on the date. https://regex101.com/r/9kvECV/1

Comment: @JadonR I have updated the pattern to match the date only.