# How to get the string between two strings in VBScript through regexp?

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have the sets of string that will always start with **?20** and end with **?30** or **?31** or **?32** and so on.

For example 
?20needed_text?30
?20needed_text?31 and so on...

I need to extract the needed text. It is necessary to stress that needed_text may contain any character including digits, letters, specific characters and etc.

Can anyone help with a proper regex?

I tried the following pattern but it does not work:

```
"\?20(.*?)\?3[0-9]"
```

this is my code. I get empty values in my echo...

```
set regex = new regexp  
regex.global = true
regex.pattern = "\?20(.*?)\?3[0-9]"
set payment_purposes = regex.execute(row)
for each payment_purpose in payment_purposes 
wscript.echo payment_purpose
next
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why doesn't it? It works perfectly. Grab `match.Submatch(0)` value. To get overlapping matches use `"\?20(.*?)(?=\?3[0-9])"`

Comment: And what is expected? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hZ9ANB/1), there is a match between `?20` and the closest `?30`. (Just realized there can be no overlapping matches here, so `\?20(.*?)\?3[0-9]` should work as per the current requirements.)

Comment: set regex = new regexp 
  regex.global = true
  regex.pattern = "\?20(.*?)(?=\?3[0-9])"
  set payment_purposes = regex.execute(row)
  for each payment_purpose in payment_purposes 
   wscript.echo payment_purpose
  next

Comment: this is my code, echo is empty :(

Comment: Are you sure the `row` text is what you expect it to be?

Comment: yes, just checked it with echo

Comment: I get `EREF+362002378231140355?21SV wwrsstung U1/U2: 001/?2200ww/12321611/1 71.39` if I use `wscript.echo payment_purpose.SubMatches.Item(0)` (or `payment_purpose.SubMatches(0)`). How do you initialize `row`? Are you sure there are no linebreaks in between the start/end markers?

Comment: Are you sure there are no linebreaks in between the start/end markers? Try replacing `.` with `[\s\S]`

Comment: There are in some places linebreaks

Comment: So, again, [this is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981809/3832970)