# Use a regular expression to find words that do match a set a set of words/codes in an input string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use JavaScript's string replace method to remove any characters or words from user input that do not match a set of words or codes within a custom pattern. For example, if I have I have a pattern `%PT!!@@` and the input `%PT1234!!test@@`, I want to remove anything that doesn't match '%PT', '!!' and '@@'. This means '1234' and 'test' will be removed from the string. I have seen similar questions using the regular expression like `(?!(%PT|!!|@@))` but this doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in plain words not regex? Since your regex you know is buggy, plain words will help to debug?

Comment: I want to remove any words or characters that don't match '%PT', '!!' or '@@'. If I do '%PT1234!!test@@''.replace(regex,''), I would have %PT!!@@ as the result.

Comment: Can you give a real world example? Otherwise removing makes no sense if it has a definite value you want.

Comment: How do you know that pattern should be `(%PT|!!|@@)` and not `(%PT!|!@@)` or `(%P|T!!@|@)`?

Comment: the pattern can be dynamic as it is defined by a user. I just used %PT!!@@ as an example

Answer (score 1):

So, you have a `%PT1234!!test@@` string and you need to remove any text that doesn't match `%PT`, `!!` and `@@` substrings.

You may capture these strings (or patterns) that you want to keep and just match everything else. Then, replace with the backreference to Group 1 to restore that value in the result.

Or, you may simple match what you need to get, and then join the found values.

See the JS demo:

```js
console.log(
  "%PT1234!!test@@".replace(/(%PT|!!|@@)|[\s\S]/g, '$1')
) // => %PT!!@@
console.log(
  "%PT1234!!test@@".match(/%PT|!!|@@/g).join("")
) // => %PT!!@@
```

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/k6sKr2/1).

**Details**

- `(%PT|!!|@@)` - Capturing group 1: any of the values listed: `%PT`, `!!` or `@@`
- `|` - or
- `[\s\S]` - any char.

Comment: The .match() function is great! Don't know why I didn't think of doing it that way. I think I was concentrating too much on the regular expression itself and removing values I didn't want rather than utilise the methods on the regex to capture the characters that did match the regex. Thanks for this, really appreciate it!

Comment: In #1 you used `[\s\S]` rather than `.`. Please explain why.

Comment: @CarySwoveland As usual, [to match any chars including line break chars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981809/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, you can use this regular expression: `/[^%PT!{2}@{2}]/g`

Quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/mzsavre5/