# How to preserve new line characters when performing a regex match in PowerShell

Tags: regex, windows, powershell

The goal is simple:

1. Take contents of text file
2. Search for pattern
3. Save search back to the file

For example, i want to find the first occurrence between `#` and `##`. Following regex works perfectly `(\#)(.*?)(?=\#{2})`. It finds what I want. However, PowerShell removes all new line characters effectively changing the formatting. So, following input text

```
#
This
Is
My
Text
##
```

becomes this

```
# This Is My Text
```

How to preserve the formatting?

Here is my PowerShell script

```
param (
    [string]$filename
)

$content = Get-Content -Path $filename
$output = $filename

$regex = [Regex]::new('(\#)(.*?)(?=\#{2})')
$matches = $regex.Matches($content)
Set-Content -Path $output $Matches[0]
```

Comment: `$content = Get-Content -Path $filename -Raw`

Comment: It stopped finding the match after I added -Raw

Comment: Because you now have a multiline string, so [use `(?s)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981809/3832970) - `[Regex]::new('(?s)(#)(.*?)(?=#{2})')`

Comment: Finally! that was easy... i spent like an hour trying everything. You can post it as an answer

Comment: All duplicate links are at the top of the page.