# Get string between with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have string like :

```
 <plaintext>10/2 (2×5 + (10 - 1)×2)</plaintext>
  </subpod>
  <expressiontypes count='1'>
   <expressiontype name='Default' />
  </expressiontypes>
 </pod>
 <pod title='Exact result'
     scanner='Rational'
     id='Result'
     position='200'
     error='false'
     numsubpods='2'
     primary='true'>
  <subpod title=''>
   <plaintext>140</plaintext>
  </subpod>

   <plaintext>Simplify the following:
(10 (2×5 + (10 - 1) 2))/2
(10 (2×5 + (10 - 1) 2))/2 = (10 (2×5 + (10 - 1) 2))/2:
(10 (2×5 + (10 - 1) 2))/2
10/2 = (2×5)/2 = 5:
5 (2×5 + (10 - 1) 2)
10 - 1 = 9:
5 (2×5 + 9×2)
2×5 = 10:
5 (10 + 9×2)
9×2 = 18:
5 (18 + 10)
 | 1 | 8
+ | 1 | 0
 | 2 | 8:
5×28
5×28 = 140:
Answer: | 
 | 140</plaintext>
```

And i want to get string between these two tags `<plaintext>` , `</plaintext>`
My code so far

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"<plaintext>(.*?)</plaintext>");
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(here is string above)
    stringBuilder.Append(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

But my regex get only string in same line but when `<plaintext>` , `</plaintext>` tags are on different lines - cant parse it.

Comment: That’s because `.*` doesn’t match new lines.

Comment: How can i fix it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression)

Comment: @404 Ok thats works perfect

Comment: That look like and Xml. why not use it as such. Either deserialize to a full object and get `object.plaintext`. Or get only the right part via Xpath or get element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `RegexOptions.Singleline` to your regex-arguments like this.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"<plaintext>(.*?)</plaintext>",
                  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Then it will capture everything except newlines.