# Why is there no "match all" special character in regex?

Tags: regex

I love regexp but I find it rather confusing why there is no "match all" special character?
For example, if I wanted to select a HTML tag and its contents, I would do

```
re = "<tag>([\s\S]*)</tag>"
```

You see, [\s\S] is a workaround to solve the absence of a match-all special character. Is there a reason why a match-all is missing from the spec? I know about `.` but it's not that pretty either:
`re = "<tag>([.\n]*)</tag>"`

Comment: If you set the `DOTALL` flag, `.` will match all.

Comment: Actually, `[^]` is another workaround

Comment: `[^]` would be neat but it caused an error in my python code. Something like "no closing brackets detected" if I remember correctly

Comment: We can't answer "why" questions like this. They are how they are.

Comment: @theX "Is there a reason why a match-all is missing from the spec?"

Comment: @Barmar I guess you could say "it is what it is". I was just assuming that there would be a historical reason. Or that people use regex in a different style (compared to mine), so, that a match-all would be considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Karveiani it’s probably because then, you’d have to type in `[^\S\s]` instead of `.`

Comment: @theX `]` appearing right after `[` or `[^` includes `]` into the character class instead of ending it (in PCRE, at least); e.g. `\[[^][]*\]` to match something in brackets. (Also: this breaks regexr.com. Funsies!)

Comment: `[.\n]` would be a `.` or new line, for new line or any character it would be `(?:.|\n)`

Comment: Find the team that developed the particular flavor of regex you're using and ask them. We can't speculate on why the did or did not provide a specific feature. The better question is why you're attempting to use a regex to parse HTML or XML when you can use a DOM parser instead. Obligatory link about the [futility of trying to parse X/HtML with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/62576).

Comment: @KenWhite Before posting this question I was wondering if match-all behaviour is considered bad practice because it's not implemented in regex. BarMar responded that it would come with performance issues. So I really don't understand why you downvoted this question

Comment: Also I'm not going to parse XML with regex so don't worry. It was an example

Comment: Who said I downvoted? I posted a comment. You should be careful about making  accusations without proof.

Comment: @KenWhite Someone downvoted my question and you were the only one coming after me in the comments.

Comment: I made basically the same comment as Barmar did, six comments above mine. Again, you should be careful about making accusations without any evidence. I didn't *come after you*. If you feel like I did, you should develop a less sensitive personality when participating here. Not every comment is an *attack*.

Comment: The answer is to use `.` and follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981809/3832970 post. Sometimes, `.` matches just any char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is the match all character. By default it doesn't match newlines, but if you set the `DOTALL` flag it will match all characters. In Python you write:

```
re.search(r"<tag>(.*)</tag>", string, re.DOTALL)
```

Why isn't this the default? Probably because most regexp applications want to limit matches to within a line (especially for performance reasons). And having two separate characters, one for "match all" and another for "match all except newline", would have been a waste of characters.

Comment: `.` **is** matching **any chars including newlines** in POSIX based regex flavors. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981809/3832970) is enough, and there is no need to re-post the same.