# Match until the first occurence of the last character of a string

Tags: regex, substring

I've tried googling this but all I can find is how to match until a known character occurs. In my case I don't know the character beforehand.

I know I can match the last character of a string with `(.?)$`, and I know that I can match until a character X occurs with `(?:(?!X).)*`, but how do I combine the two to match until the first occurence and not the matched occurence?

Examples:

> character → char
> test → t
> no match → no match
> This is a test → This is a t
> I came. I saw. I conquered. → I came.

In pseudocode what I want is basically `str.substring(0,str.indexOf(str.lastChar))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?=(.)*$).*?\1
^(?=.*(.)$).*?\1
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MXpKwn/1). If you need to match multiline strings, see how  [How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(.)*$)` - a positive lookahead capturing each char other than line break chars up to the end of string (last one is saved in Group 1)
- `.*?` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\1` - same char as in Group 1.