# How to match multiple lines string using regex in python? (Tried all the methods found)

Tags: python, regex

My data look like this:

```
data = "2020-11-16 18:07:12,752 part1: 3, part2: [0.43732753 0.53800666 0.5945345  0.4680181  0.39867717 0.6513964
 0.6692839  0.5011144  0.41480267 0.40932187 0.40816575 0.44242284
 0.56950533 0.54023486 0.46301603 0.46460354], part3: 0.3253246169133328
2020-11-16 18:07:23,940 part1: 4, part2: [0.4273718  0.5393375  0.591234   0.46008328 0.3886507  0.658916
 0.7164184  0.37173408 0.42199427 0.5302575  0.34260145 0.5678605
 0.5731818  0.5455015  0.45556515 0.47291118], part3: 0.37686885359458105"
```

I want to extract everything after the time, namely after part1 to the end of part3. The desired output should look like:

```
output = "part1: 3, part2: [0.43732753 0.53800666 0.5945345  0.4680181  0.39867717 0.6513964
     0.6692839  0.5011144  0.41480267 0.40932187 0.40816575 0.44242284
     0.56950533 0.54023486 0.46301603 0.46460354], part3: 0.3253246169133328"
```

But the multiple line stuff is making everything break. My current code looks like this.

```
output = re.findall(r"part1:(.*)\d{4}-\d{2}", data,re.DOTALL)[0]
```

I tried all the methods I found including all in this post:
[How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression) 
Namely, I tried replacing `(.\*)` with `([\s\S]\*)` or `(.|\n|\r\*)` or `((?s).\*)` and their combinations with the `re.DOTALL` and `re.MULTILINE` flags. None of them worked. Could anyone help me out?

update: I tried `part1:((.\*)\n)\*?(.\*)part3(.\*)` and it worked on the finder in VSCode. But it doesn't work for python.

Comment: Not sure how you are getting away with it, but wrap multiple lines in triple quotes.

Comment: Also warp the `part1:` in braces cause you need that right. And don't make the regex anymore complicated than nescessary.

Comment: @SouyamaDebnath Thank you for your idea! It didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Then read the whole file in usign `open(filepath, 'r').read()`. Do not read file line by line.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Solved! Thank you so much!