# Postgres Regex: extract string after the last occurence of the pattern and the end of line

Tags: regex, string, postgresql, pattern-matching

Please help me to extract the text after the last occurrence of the `Schedule :`  and the end of the line.

```
Lane Closures : Lane one will be closed
Reason : Roadworks are planned
Status : Pending
Schedule : Expect disruption everyday between 20:00 and 06:00 from 5 October 2020 to 9 October 2020
Schedule : Expect disruption everyday between 20:00 and 06:00 from 12 October 2020 to 16 October 2020
Schedule : Expect disruption everyday between 20:00 and 06:00 from 19 October 2020 to 23 October 2020
Schedule : Expect disruption everyday between 20:00 and 06:00 from 26 October 2020 to 31 October 2020
Lanes Closed : There will be one of two lanes closed
```

In the above case, I need to extract `Expect disruption everyday between 20:00 and 06:00 from 26 October 2020 to 31 October 2020`

So far I came up only with the following:

```
(?<=Schedule : ).*(?![\s\S]*Schedule)
```

But it doesn't work in Postgres. It returns error:
`invalid regular expression: invalid escape \ sequence`

I also tried to replace `\s` and `\S` with `[:space:]` and `^[:space:]` as per [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html) but it doesn't work either

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In PostgreSQL, you do not need `[\s\S]`, just use a dot, `.`. Thus, you need `(?<=Schedule : )[^\r\n]+(?!.*Schedule)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a [`.` in a PostgreSQL regex matches any char including line break chars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981809/3832970), you need to introduce two changes:

- The first `.*` should be replaced with `[^\r\n]+` to match any chars other than common line break chars
- The `[\s\S]` in the lookahead should be replaced with a mere `.`.

You can use

```sql
(?<=Schedule : )[^\r\n]+(?!.*Schedule)
```

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/QZJC51145):

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES(
    E'Lane Closures : Lane one will be closed\nReason : Roadworks are planned\nStatus : Pending\nSchedule : Expect disruption everyday between 20:00 and 06:00 from 5 October 2020 to 9 October 2020\nSchedule : Expect disruption everyday between 20:00 and 06:00 from 12 October 2020 to 16 October 2020\nSchedule : Expect disruption everyday between 20:00 and 06:00 from 19 October 2020 to 23 October 2020\nSchedule : Expect disruption everyday between 20:00 and 06:00 from 26 October 2020 to 31 October 2020\nLanes Closed : There will be one of two lanes closed', 
    '(?<=Schedule : )[^\r\n]+(?!.*Schedule)', 
    'g')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @DmytroSly Just FYI, you do not need the lookbehind, just use a capturing group around the pattern part you need to extract, `'Schedule\s*:\s*([^\r\n]+)(?!.*Schedule)'` would work the same here.