# Regex - match first 1000 symbols

Tags: regex, notepad++

Im using OpenOffice and Notepad++.

Need to match around first 1000 symbols (or less) in text until end of the sentence (dot sign). For example:

```
"Once upon a time ... around 1000 symbols ... the end.",
```

Then you click next search and get match of another around 1000 symbols that ends with `.` sign and so on.

I tried regex `(?s).*` that matches everything and `.{0,1000}` that stops when reaches line break.

I think I need something like `.{0,1000}\.\n\r` or `.{0,1000}\.\S\s`. I noticed that I need include things like `e.g.` in the regex, otherwise it matches `...e.` and leaves `g.` apart. How to do that?

Comment: what do you mean when you say "**symbols**"?

Comment: `.` in regex means any character so you have to escape it like `\.` to capture the end of a sentence that ends with a period. Or you can use `[.]` as well.

Comment: Vishal, by symbol I mean any character

Comment: Use `[\s\S]{1000}.*?\.`.

Comment: You want the single line flag.  Some regex parsers have a way to specify flags outside the pattern, others allow you to set flags inside the pattern.  For the latter, you want `(?s).{0,1000}`

Comment: MIchael, I tried ".{0,1000}\.\n" with no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Actually,`(?s).{0,1000}\.` must work for you.

Comment: [\s\S]{1000}.*?\. by @41686d6564 works great in notepad++, thanks.  I noticed that I need include things like "e.g." in the end otherwise regex match "...e." and leaves "g." apart. How to do that?

Comment: Try `(?s).{1000}(?-s).*?\.\B`

Comment: I added e.g. and ?: `(?s).{0,600}(\.|e.g.|\?)`. It works fine, but not totally tested.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, `(?s).{1000}(?-s).*?\.\B` matches sometimes much more than 1000 characters, it must be 1000 or less.

Comment: @StanHf. If it must be 1000 chars at most (which you haven't mentioned in the question) including the dot, then `[\s\S]{1,999}\.` should work for you. This is the same as `(?s).{1,999}\.` (or just `.{1,999}\.` when the `. matches newline` checkbox is checked).

Comment: Your requirements are far from clear, we are just trying to follow your comments. Now, you say it must be less than 1K chars, so, my suggestion must be adjusted to `(?s).{1,999}\.\B`. This will match max 1K chars, or less if the `.` occurs closer to the beginning. It can really match just two chars, BTW.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, `(?s).{1,999}\.\B` does not match if there is "?" in the end.  Look like `(?s).{0,1000}(\.|e.g.|\?)`  works best.

Comment: Ok, you just want to match sentence end punctuation. Use `(?s).{1,1000}[.?!…]\B`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew,  as I said "1000 or less", it means  =< 1000, so {0,1000} is the right code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew,  `(?s).{0,1000}[.?!…]\B` works great, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?s).{0,1000}[.?!…]\B
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zYlSe8/1).

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL modifier, `.` now matches line break chars
- `.{0,1000}` - any 0 to 1000 chars
- `[.?!…]\B` - a `.`, `?`, `!` or `…` that is either at the end of string or that is followed with a non-word char.