# How to make a regex negative lookahead stop?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'd like to match a string with the following conditions

- must start with an `A`
- followed by any count of anything unless it's two consecutive upper case letter
- followed by a number (which should be captured)

`A bcd 1`  should match and capture `1`

`Abcd1`  should match and capture `1`

`A bcd`   should not match because there is no number

`A BCd 1`  should not match because there is a capital `C` between the `A` and the number

`A bcd 1 EF` should match because `1` is before the `EF`

I came up with

```
A(?!.*[A-Z]{2})+?.*(\d+)
```

but that does not work for the last use case because the negative lookahead goes beyond the `1`

Here is a playground https://regex101.com/r/1zRCrp/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `(?!.*[A-Z]{2})+?` is the same as `(?!.*[A-Z]{2})` as the lookahead only needs to be executed once (`+?` matches one or more but as few as possible occurrences, quantifying lookbehinds is always a wrong idea). The `.*` matches any chars other than line break chars as many as possible, so it will grab all text up to the last digit and `(\d+)` thus captures the last digit on a matching line.

You can use

```
A(?:(?![A-Z]{2}).)*?(\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1zRCrp/4).

*Details*:

- `A` - an `A` letter
- `(?:(?![A-Z]{2}).)*?` - zero or more (but as few as possible) occurrences of a char other than line break chars that does not start a two-uppercase letter char sequence
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits.

If you need to match across multiple lines see solutions in [How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/159118/3832970)

Comment: sorry I updated my question just before you answered. The condition to stop the lookahead is "anything except two consecutive uppercase letters"

Comment: @Jan I updated the pattern to match your exact pattern requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You could exclude matching digits in the lookahead and in the match using `\D`

```
A(?!\D*[A-Z]{2})\D*(\d+)
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/QgWaO2/1).

---

To not cross newlines you can use `[^\d\n]`

If you also want to prevent `A` from being part of a partial word match, you can append a word boundary `\bA`

```
\bA(?![^\d\n]*[A-Z]{2})[^\d\n]*(\d+)
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/a5YtLC/1).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of capturing the digits you can also use `\K` to reset the match upon encountering a digit so that the digits can be the entirety of the match outright:

```
^A(?:(?![A-Z]{2}).).*?\K\d+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/JvrSIR/1