# How do I extract a piece of a multi-line string with regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have a multi-line string that I'm trying to extract, but it is not returning any pieces.

```
$input = '<script>
buffy = 1;
vampire = {
response: [{"sleep":"night"}]
};
</script>';

preg_match( '~response:(.*?)};~', $input, $output );

print_r( $output );
```

I am trying to extract `[{"sleep":"night"}]`

Comment: Either that, or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981809). Use the `s` modifier: [`(?s)response:\s*\K.*?(?=\s*};)`](https://regex101.com/r/o9EuIY/1).

Comment: Try [`response\s*:\s*\K((?:\[(?1)\]|\{(?1)\}|[^][{}]*?)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/L3wW2C/1)

Comment: `.` Matches any character other than newline (or including line terminators with the /s flag) .   So you need to replace `.*?` with `[\s\S]*?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out :

```
$input = '<script>
buffy = 1;
vampire = {
response: [{"sleep":"night"}]
};
</script>';

preg_match('/response:\s*([^;]+);/', $input, $output);

print_r($output[1]);
```

Comment: That's getting there -- but there's a `}` left over

Comment: @Kermit is this what you want ? `preg_match( '/response:\s*(\[.*?\])/', $input, $output );`

Answer (score 0):

```
'~response: (\[\{[^}]+}])~'

response    interpret as text
:           interpret as text
            interpret as text (one space)
(           start of capturing group
\[          interpret as text
\{          interpret as text
[^}]        anything up to the next }
+           ... and do this one or more times
}           interpret as text
]           interpret as text
)           end of capturing group
```