Regex -- match up until an OPTIONAL end word
Similar to this question, I want a regex to match until an end word. However, if the end word does not exist, I want to match the whole test string.
Examples inputs and desired match:
" \n SELECT id FROM table WHERE country=US" => " \n SELECT id FROM table"
" \n SELECT id FROM table" => " \n SELECT id FROM table"
" \n SELECT id FROM table GROUP BY" => " \n SELECT id FROM table GROUP BY"

This only works for the first case:
.*FROM.*(?:WHERE)

But I can't figure out how to make the other cases work in conjunction.

Match up to the end word or $.

First, WHERE should be in a lookahead, not a non-capture group, if you don't want it included in the match.
Use $ as alternative in the lookahead. Then use a non-greedy quantifier so you stop at the first match.
.*FROM.*?(?=WHERE|$)

DEMO

Awesome, this answers the question but I perhaps oversimplified my example. Is there a way to make this approach work with across newlines? ex:
SELECT \n
  id \n
FROM \n
  table \n
WHERE country=US

This regex matches on the word FROM but does not include the word "table" in the match:
.*FROM(.|\n)*?(?:WHERE|$)


Use the DOTALL (s) flag when doing the regexp match to make . match newlines.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression

The details of how you do that depends on the language you're using.

Thanks, that does solve the simple example, but it seems a second matching start word ("FROM") causes the stop word ("WHERE") to not stop: https://regex101.com/r/nmD4U3/1
Accepting this answer but might have to split my string in pieces first.

You can use another non-greedy quantifier before FROM, so that will match the first instance rather than the last one.
